# C# Regex Validator Validation

Tags: c#, .net, regex, validation

I have this

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator7" runat="server"    
     ControlToValidate="txtLastName"Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Alphabetic characters only"
     ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z'.\-\s]{1,50)$"
></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

but now i want to change it and make a Regex that will let the user to insert 1 character but not one of the special chars in the expression above, nor to start with one of those 
special chars(also include "." spacial char".

NOTE : I want those specials to be accepted after the first char is alphabetic

thnx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z'.\s\-]{0,50}` :D //revised 1 to 0

Comment: That totally did the job. Thnx!! :D

Answer (score 2):

Try this `^[a-zA-Z'.\-\s]{1}$|^[a-zA-Z'.\-\s]{1}[\w]*$`

Comment: @Abhishek Simon couldnt set property to validator

Comment: @Ranhiru Cooray Thanks both of you it works perfectly but i found the need to also validate the "."and to accept the specials after the first is alphabetic

Comment: @vkline: I obviously cannot take any credit. All I did was just make the answer look prettier :) Glad you could find the answer :)

Comment: @Ranhiru Cooray But can you help me with my new problem :). I want this regex to not accept also .(dot) for first char and also after the first character is alphabetic those special chars to be accepted. cause at the monet C# doesnt semm to work. It accepts normally the dot and after the first char is alphabetic it doenst accept any special char.

Comment: @vkline: Does this work? ^[a-zA-Z'.\-\s\.]{1}$|^[a-zA-Z'.\-\s\.]{1}[\w+]*$

Comment: @Abhishek Simon Nop it still accepts .(dot) for first char. and doesnt accept special char when the first char is alphabetical